# Differences between different methods of Symfony service collection

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, containers

For those of you that are familiar with the building of the Symfony container, do you know what is the differences (if any) between

1. [Tagged service Collector](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/tags.html#create-a-compiler-pass) using a Compiler pass
2. Tagged service Collector [using the supported shortcut](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/tags.html#reference-tagged-services)
3. [Service Locator](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_subscribers_locators.html#defining-a-service-locator) especially, one that [collects services by tags](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_subscribers_locators.html#indexing-the-collection-of-services)

Specifically, I am wondering about whether these methods differ on making these collected services available sooner or later in the container build process. Also I am wondering about the ‘laziness’ of any of them.

Comment: Which kind of "difference" are you refering to?

Comment: as it says above: Specifically, I am wondering about whether these methods differ on making these collected services available sooner or later in the container build process. Also I am wondering about the ‘laziness’ of any of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can certainly be confusing when trying to understand the differences.  Keep in mind that the latter two approaches are fairly new.  The documentation has not quite caught up.  You might actually consider making a new project and doing some experimenting.

Approach 1 is basically an "old school" style.  You have:

```
class MyCollector {
    private $handlers = [];
    public function addHandler(MyHandler $hamdler) {
        $handlers[] = $handler;
# compiler pass
$myCollectorDefinition->addMethodCall('addHandler', [new Reference($handlerServiceId)]);
```

So basically the container will instantiate MyCollector then explicitly call addHandler for each handler service.  In doing so, the handler services will be instantiated unless you do some proxy stuff.  So no lazy creation.

The second approach provides a somewhat similar capability but uses an iterable object instead of a plain php array:

```
class MyCollection {
    public function __construct(iterable $handlers)
# services.yaml
    App\MyCollection:
        arguments:
            - !tagged_iterator my.handler
```

One nice thing about this approach is that the iterable actually ends up connecting to the container via closures and will only instantiate individual handlers when they are actually accessed.  So lazy handler creation.  Also, there are some variations on how you can specify the key.

I might point out that typically you auto-tag your individual handlers with:

```
# services.yaml
services:
    _instanceof:
        App\MyHandlerInterface:
            tags: ['my.handler']
```

So no compiler pass needed.

The third approach is basically the same as the second except that handler services can be accessed individually by an index.  This is useful when you need one out of all the possible services.  And of course the service selected is only created when you ask for it.

```
class MyCollection {
    public function __construct(ServiceLocator $locator) {
        $this->locator = $locator;
    }
    public function doSomething($handlerKey) {
        /** @var MyHandlerInterface $handler */
        $handler = $serviceLocator->get($handlerKey);
# services.yaml
    App\MyCollection:
        arguments: [!tagged_locator { tag: 'app.handler', index_by: 'key' }]
```

I should point out that in all these cases, the code does not actually know the class of your handler service.  Hence the var comment to keep the IDE happy.

There is another approach which I like in which you make your own ServiceLocator and then specify the type of object being located.  No need for a var comment.  Something like:

```
class MyHandlerLocator extends ServiceLocator
{
    public function get($id) : MyHandlerInterface
    {
        return parent::get($id);
    }
}
```

The only way I have been able to get this approach to work is a compiler pass.  I won't post the code here as it is somewhat outside the scope of the question.  But in exchange for a few lines of pass code you get a nice clean custom locator which can also pick up handlers from other bundles.

Comment: thank you _so much_ for your answer! Could you clarify what you meant by "the code does not actually know anything about the handler class itself" - I assume you are referring to IDE use, etc? Also, do you know if any of these methods happen earlier or later in the container build process and if that even matters? The problem I am trying to fix is that I used #1 above but one of the collected services is not available 'quickly enough' after the container gets nuked.

Comment: I made a slight update.  With the out of the box configuration, you need a /** var comment to tell your IDE what class is being used.  Which I find annoying. A custom ServiceLocator eliminates the need.

Comment: Order should not matter.  I don't know what you mean by 'nuking' the container.  Consider creating a simple example and opening a new specific question.

Comment: thank you again. I simply meant deleting the container class to force a rebuild. I am working with a system that dynamically loads bundles based on a state var in the DB. When the state declares the bundle should be loaded and it was not previously, the container needs to be recompiled. This service locator should add a service from the new bundle, but it seems to not be doing so early enough in the process to be recognized when it is called in a controller, like $serviceLoc->get('NewBundleClass')

Comment: Hmmm.  I see nothing 'simple' in the process you described.  No idea what could be going on.